# Get value from @Subscribe

Tags: android, events, otto

I have a class where I receive an event - a boolean variable in this case, using **EventBus/Otto**(for Fragment/Activity or something similar for posibility to subscribe in simple class) like:

```
  @Subscribe
             public void onSubscribeMyData(boolean myData) {

             if(myData){
             Log.d("LOG_TAG", "my received string is true");
                  }   

             else{
             Log.d("LOG_TAG", "my received string is false");
                  }    
              }
```

**UPDATE**
My class contains only this method:

```
//check network

   public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        String ip = "217.26.147.42";
        AsyncTaskIsOnline taskIsOnline = new AsyncTaskIsOnline();
        taskIsOnline.execute(ip);

        return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && myReceivedVariable;
    }
```

so, how can I asign received **myData** to **myReceivedVariable** but this class is instantiated evrey time when i make server call

I tried to asign value to global variables or wrap this boolean in a object and use set/get but no success...

Comment: If you'd like you can save the data received in a SharedPreference and this can be retrieved from anywhere in you application.

Comment: yes but I need this value in live time, every request, and using Shared Preferences I am late with one value

Comment: If the class you need to receive the data is an activity or a fragment you can send broadcast to them in the onSubscribeMyData method, that way for every call, a broadcast intent will be sent to the classes registered for such broadcast.

Comment: well, this is a simple class, for chech internet connection+aviability only, I updated my code for clarity